# SwiftUI: How to prevent `onSubmit` on TextField from hiding keyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

This simple `TextField` might be part of a chat feature, and I would like to be able to send chat messages when I press the keyboard button "send".

(Imagine in this chat I don't need to allow users to enter newline, by overriding the *return* key, to be *send* with the `submitLabel(.send)` view modifier.)

```swift
TextField(
    "Chat...",
    text: $draft
)
.submitLabel(.send)
.onSubmit {
    if !draft.isEmpty {
        sendMessage(draft: draft)
    }
}
```

However, this will hide the keyboard, and I would like to know:

**is there any way to prevent the keyboard from hiding when I press `send`??**

I know how to refocus the field, I can do that with `@FocusState` but that still results in a hide keyboard animation starting which then aborts, so looks glithy.

Comment: When should the keyboard hide itself then?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson .eg. in `onTapGesture` on the whole chat view :)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to prevent keyboard hiding using a somewhat "hacky" solution, combing *re-focus of field* together with *disable animation*.

```swift
struct ChatView {
    enum Field: String, Hashable {
        case chat
    }
    @State var draft = ""
    @FocusState var focusedField: Field?

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            // messages view omitted
            TextField(
                "Chat...",
                text: $draft
            )
            .submitLabel(.send)
            .onSubmit {
                if !draft.isEmpty {
                    sendMessage()
                    // We just lost focus because "return" key was pressed
                    // we re-fucus
                    focusedField = .chat
                }
            }

            Button("Send") {
                sendMessage()
            }
        } 
        // Prevent hacky keyboard hide animation
        .transaction { $0.animation = nil }
    }    

    func sendMessage() {
       // impl omitted, sending message `draft` using some dependency.
    }
}
```

Comment: My solution vs @vacawama (exact same idea) solves ont important thing, if we do not put the `transaction` modifier on the parent (`VStack`) the send `Button` "jumps"...

Comment: Unfortunately this hack no longer works with iOS 16, there the problem is exaggerated. Please file bugs.

Answer (score 0):

on ios16 the keyboard bounces back everytime when you click on send.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).