# how can I keep the keyboard opened with @FocusState with SwiftUI without a bounce?

Tags: swiftui, textfield

I am trying to develop a view where the user must input his name and surname. these two textfields have a FocusState. Everything is working well less a little bounce when the focus changes his goal.
[image: bounce app]

I do not know what is happening in my code for this issue.
this is my code:

```
struct OnboardingViewPart2: View {

enum Field: Hashable{
    case name
    case surname
}

@State var displayName         = ""
@State var showImagePicker     = false
@State var isSomePhotoSelected = false
@State var displaySurname      = ""
@FocusState var focusedField : Field?


// For image picker
@State var imageSelected: UIImage = UIImage(systemName: "person.fill")!
@State var sourceType: UIImagePickerController.SourceType = .photoLibrary

var body: some View {
    
    VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 20, content: {
```

//other code

```
        // MARK: Textfield group
        Group{
            
            TextField("Add your name here...", text: $displayName)
                .padding()
                .frame(height: 60)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .background(Color.MyTheme.beige)
                .cornerRadius(12)
                .font(.headline)
                .autocapitalization(.sentences)
                .padding(.horizontal)
                .focused($focusedField, equals: .name)
            
            TextField("Add your surname here...", text: $displaySurname)
                .padding()
                .frame(height: 60)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .background(Color.MyTheme.beige)
                .cornerRadius(12)
                .font(.headline)
                .autocapitalization(.sentences)
                .padding(.horizontal)
                .focused($focusedField, equals: .surname)
        }
        .onSubmit {focusedField = focusedField == .name ? .surname : nil}
        
        //other code
        
    }) // VStack
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    .background(Color.MyTheme.purple)
    //.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    .sheet(isPresented: $showImagePicker, content: {
        ImagePicker(imageSelected: $imageSelected, sourceType: $sourceType, isSomeImageSelected: $isSomePhotoSelected)
    }) // Picker
    
    
}
```

}

// Updated!!

after updating the code with the proposed solution this is the new result:
[image: new result]

Comment: Perhaps this Q&A will help:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/73634297/1630618

Comment: I have implemented the solutions proposed in that link but it´s not working yet. I got this result. I have edited the post.

Comment: That workaround doesn't seem to work with iOS16. :-(

Comment: Did you figure out a solution? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: while the moment I have not found a solution. if I find out how to fix it I will publish it

Comment: You can fix this by using `UITextField` and `UITextView`. Using `becomeFirstResponder` would not occur this behavior. [art-technologies/swift-focuser](https://github.com/art-technologies/swift-focuser) is a good choice to fix it but as this repository isn't maintained anymore so maybe you have to fix some problems by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a little too late, but I've just run in to this problem and found a solution that's working well for me.

```
class TextFieldDelegate: NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate {
    
    var shouldReturn: (() -> Bool)?
    
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        
        if let shouldReturn = shouldReturn {
            return shouldReturn()
        }
        else {
            return true
        }
    }
}
```

Then in my SwiftUI view:

```
import Introspect

struct TestView: View {
    
    enum FocusedField {
        case username, password
    }
    
    @State private var username: String = ""
    @State private var password: String = ""
    
    var usernameFieldDelegate = TextFieldDelegate()
    var passwordFieldDelegate = TextFieldDelegate()
    
    @FocusState private var focusedField: FocusedField?
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            
            TextField(text: $username)
                .focused($focusedField, equals: .username)
                .introspectTextField(customize: { textField in
                    
                    usernameFieldDelegate.shouldReturn = {
                        
                        if usernameIsValid() {
                            focusedField = .password
                        }
                        
                        return false
                    }
                    
                    textField.delegate = usernameFieldDelegate
                })
            
            SecureField(text: $password)
                .focused($focusedField, equals: .password)
                .introspectTextField(customize: { textField in
                    
                    passwordFieldDelegate.shouldReturn = {
                        validateAndProceed()
                        
                        return false
                    }
                    
                    textField.delegate = passwordFieldDelegate
                })
        }
    }
    
    func usernameIsValid() -> Bool {
        return true
    }
    
    func validateAndProceed() {}
}
```